# Restrict Firebase Database rules using unique key generated to every user. (Android studio)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Hey I'm working on an app that lets students students save their schedule and access it whenever they need it.
I save their schedule on firebase database attaching unique ID to every user and saving their lessons' name and respective school hour as children to the unique ID.

question is, how do I setup firebase rules to restrict every user to modify only data stored under his unique key.

it looks like this
[image: it looks like this]

rules are currently public for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-K...` value seems to be a push ID, which is not a valid Firebase Authentication UID. So from that I get a feeling your users don't sign in. And while you can definitely come up with a system where push IDs identify users, those IDs don't carry over to  Firebase Authentication or to Firebase Database security rules. To be honest: it would be quite insecure if they would carry over.

If you want to identify your users securely without asking them to sign in with email+password or a social provider, use [Firebase's anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth). To the user it works the same: they don't have to sign in. But to Firebase it means that they're a properly authenticated user with a real UID. And the code is as simple as:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInAnonymously()
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            Log.d(TAG, "signInAnonymously:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.w(TAG, "signInAnonymously", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(AnonymousAuthActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            // ...
        }
    });
```

And to detect the signed in user (which also picks them up again when they restart the app):

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            // User is signed in
            Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
        } else {
            // User is signed out
            Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
        }
        // ...
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks, where do I put this tho? wherever I want to sign them in?

Comment: The first snippet is where you actually sign them in. The second snippet should go in `onCreate` or `onStart`. Please have a look at the docs I linked for further explanation, since that contains the working code that I copied above.